# useEffect unwanted side effect when refresh page

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks, setstate

In my account page, after logging in, I want to display dynamic ways of greeting plus the name of the user from the firebase users document. I use react typed for the greetings.

When I login, everything seems to work well; but, when I refresh the page, all the content vanish and in console I get the following error message:

> index.esm2017.js:1032 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of
> undefined (reading 'indexOf').

However, if I remove the user from dependencies array in `useEffect`, the error is gone but, in the console, I see how it loops infinitely. I think this is because of react typed.

Can someone, please, tell me what am I doing wrong and explain how to use `useEffect` properly in this situation?

Here is the code:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Typed from "react-typed";
import { UserAuth } from "../contexts/AuthContext";
import { db } from "../utils/firebase/firebase.utils";
import { doc, getDoc } from "firebase/firestore";

const Hero = () => {
  const [userDetails, setUserDetails] = useState({});
  const { user } = UserAuth();

  useEffect(() => {
    const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);

    const fetchData = async () => {
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      setUserDetails(docSnap.data());
      console.log(docSnap.data());
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [user]);

  return (
    <div className="text-white">
      <div className="max-w-[800px] mt-[-96px] w-full h-screen mx-auto text-center flex flex-col justify-center">
        <div className="flex justify-center items-center">
          <Typed
            className="md:text-5xl sm:text-4xl text-xl font-bold md:pl-4 pl-2"
            strings={["Hello,", "Hola,"]}
            typeSpeed={120}
            backSpeed={140}
            loop
          />
          <p className="md:text-5xl sm:text-4xl text-xl font-bold py-4">
            {userDetails.displayName}!
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Hero;
```

Answer (score 1):

Likely the error is being caused because user or userDetails doesn't exist when your `useEffect` is run for the first time and `user.uid` is causing the error.

Can do something like this to solve the issue

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (!user) return;

    const docRef = doc(db, "users", user.uid);

    const fetchData = async () => {
      const docSnap = await getDoc(docRef);
      setUserDetails(docSnap.data());
      console.log(docSnap.data());
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [user]);

if (!user && userDetails === {}) {
  return <div>Loading.</div<
}
```

Though the UserAuth() hook might have a loading property that it returns that can be used instead for a better way of doing this.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error.